# Collapse multiple rows of strings into one row based on a condition.

Tags: r, regex, split

Say I had this data:

```
df <- data.frame(
   text = c("Treatment1: This text is","on two lines","","Treatment2:This text","has","three lines","","Treatment3: This has one")
                  )
df
                      text
1 Treatment1: This text is
2             on two lines
3                         
4     Treatment2:This text
5                      has
6              three lines
7                         
8 Treatment3: This has one
```

How would I parse this text so that all the "Treatments" are on their own row with all the text below on the same row?

For example this is the desired output:

```
text
1 Treatment1: This text is on two lines
2 Treatment2: This text has three lines                
3 Treatment3: This has one
```

Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like the following.
First, the data in `dput` format, the best format to share datasets in posts.

```
df <-
structure(list(text = c("Treatment1: This text is", "on two lines", 
"", "Treatment2:This text", "has", "three lines", "", "Treatment3: This has one"
)), .Names = "text", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Now the `base R` code.

```
fact <- cumsum(grepl("treatment", df$text, , ignore.case = TRUE))
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, fact), function(x)
                     trimws(paste(x$text, collapse = " "))))
result <- as.data.frame(result)
names(result) <- "text"
result
#                                   text
#1 Treatment1: This text is on two lines
#2  Treatment2:This text has three lines
#3              Treatment3: This has one
```

**EDIT.**
As Rich Scriven points out in his comment, `tapply` can greatly simplify the code above. (I didn't see that, sometimes I complicate too much.)

```
result2 <- data.frame(
    text = tapply(df$text, fact, function(x) trimws(paste(x, collapse = " ")))
)

all.equal(result, result2)
#[1] "Component “text”: 'current' is not a factor"
```

Comment: Have a look at `tapply()`.  It can replace `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(...), ...))`

Comment: @RichScriven Thank you, answer edited with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- gsub("\\s+Treatment", "*BREAK*Treatment",
          as.character(paste(df[[1]], collapse = " ")))
data.frame(text = unlist(strsplit(x, "\\*BREAK\\*")))
```